# Rails scope filter/search from association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a one-to-one association between PublicKey and PublicKeyRole. The PublicKey model has a column, `role_id`, and the PublicKeyRole model has `role` column which is a string, such as `'super'`.

I want to be able to search by role string via a url query param, like; `https://api.domain.com/public_keys?role=admin`. I've tried this on the PublicKey model but I'm not sure where to pass the query in to:

```
scope :filter_by_role, lambda { |query|
  joins(:public_key_role).merge(PublicKeyRole.role)
}
```

Here are my models:

```
class PublicKey < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :public_key_role, foreign_key: :role_id

  def self.search(params = {})
    public_keys = params[:public_key_ids].present? ? PublicKey.where(id: params[:public_key_ids]) : PublicKey.all
    public_keys = public_keys.filter_by_role(params[:role]) if params[:role]

    public_keys
  end
end

class PublicKeyRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :public_key
end
```

Also, here's my test:

```
describe '.filter_by_role' do
    before(:each) do
      @public_key1 = FactoryGirl.create :public_key, { role_id: 1 }
      @public_key2 = FactoryGirl.create :public_key, { role_id: 2 }
      @public_key3 = FactoryGirl.create :public_key, { role_id: 1 }
    end

    context "when a 'super' role is sent" do
      it 'returns the 2 matching public keys results' do
        expect(PublicKey.filter_by_role('super').size).to eq(2)
      end

      it 'returns the matching public keys' do
        expect(PublicKey.filter_by_role('super').sort).to match_array([@public_key1, @public_key3])
      end
    end
  end
```

#### Update

I was missing the following in my spec, @lcguida's answer works.

```
FactoryGirl.create :public_key_role, { id: 1, role: 'super' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#merging-of-scopes) you have some examples. You can search in the relation passing the query to the PublicKeyRole relation:

```
scope :filter_by_role, lambda { |query|
  joins(:public_key_role).merge(PublicKeyRole.where(role: query))
}
```

If you want a string search (as LIKE):

```
scope :filter_by_role, lambda { |query|
  joins(:public_key_role).merge(PublicKeyRole.where(PublicKeyRole.arel_table[:role].matches(query)))
}
```

Comment: role is the string attribute of PublickKeyRole?

Comment: Looks like my spec was missing the public_key_role model. Both of these seem to work.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the parenthesis. SO wouldn't allow me to make a single edit, it needed a minimum of 6 characters or something.